# HTML disable Drop event, div box child contents overlap

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, overlap

I followed the drag&drop tutorial online, and test it a little bit on my own. Then I realized a problem: so I dragged image1 to Box A and image2 to Box B, then i'm trying to drag image1 from Box A to Box B, the issue appears. If I drop image1 on the edge of Box B, everything works fine, both images are in the Box B, if I drop image1 on top of image2, image1 disappeared. does anyone know how to prevent this? I want box both image shows in the box no matter how I drop them.

my example link:http://qcn.freeiz.com/VisTool/DnDrp%20Test.htm

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Learn about [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and understand that `ev.target` is initially the element the `drop` event occurred on, not the element you attached the listener to.  Check what `ev.target` is before doing `appendChild` and `ev.preventDefault()`.  [Here is a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/arumL/):

```
function dragDrop(ev) {
    var eleid = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var el = ev.target;
    if (el.id != 'dropzone' && el.id != 'dropzone2') {
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    el.appendChild(document.getElementById(eleid));
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```