# How to stop overlapping of divs in drag and drop using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a page in which there are some draggable divs on the left and 4 boxes on right in which those divs can be dropped, but when I drop the div on another,

[image]

something like this happens. I want them not to overlap but align themselves automatically, like in JQuery Sortable: this:http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#placeholder.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);

    }

     function drop(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
```

```css
 <style type="text/css">
.gh{width:96%;height:auto;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;clear: both;margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;overflow:none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;

}

.leftbox{clear: both;
  border:2px solid green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: none;
  overflow:scroll;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
  background:white;
  position: absolute;



}
.leftbox2{
  border:2px solid green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: none;
  overflow:scroll;
  transition: all 1s ease;
z-index: 1;
  background:white;
  position: absolute;



}
.rightbox{clear: both;
  border:3px solid red;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow:scroll;
  transition: all 2s ease;



}
.rightbox2{clear: both;
  border:3px solid red;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow:scroll;
  transition: all 2s ease;



}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.go{
min-height:300px;
height: 800px;
width: 100%;
overflow:scroll;

  }
  .btn{
    width: 100%;
  }

  </style>
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-4 me">
  <div class="big-title">

    <h1 class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
        Wishlist
    </h1>
</div>
<div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="go">

      <ul>
      <li >


      <div id="drag0" class="gh col-md-12"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >
      sdfd


     </div>

      </li>          
        <li>
        <div id="drag3" class="gh col-md-12"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    dasdsa
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="drag4" class="gh col-md-12"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img class="img img-responsive col-md-4" src="images/blog-mini-01.jpg">

      <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="big-title" style="text-align:center">
<h3>This is a sample tfa jkljankjbfhbfklhabitle</h3>
</div>

<ul class="col-md-12">


         <li class="col-md-6 pull-left"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Fees</i></li>
         <li class="col-md-6 pull-right"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Rating</i></li>

       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Duration </i></li>
       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> University </i></li>

         </ul>
         </div>
       <div>
         <ul>
         <li class="col-md-6">
         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go to course>></a>
         </li>
         <li class="col-md-6">

         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Remove</a>
</li>         
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="drag5" class="gh col-md-12"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img class="img img-responsive col-md-4" src="images/blog-mini-01.jpg">

      <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="big-title" style="text-align:center">
<h3>This is a sample tfa jkljankjbfhbfklhabitle</h3>
</div>

<ul class="col-md-12">


         <li class="col-md-6 pull-left"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Fees</i></li>
         <li class="col-md-6 pull-right"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Rating</i></li>

       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Duration </i></li>
       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> University </i></li>

         </ul>
         </div>
       <div>
         <ul>
         <li class="col-md-6">
         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go to course>></a>
         </li>
         <li class="col-md-6">

         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Remove</a>
</li>         
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="drag43" class="gh col-md-12"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img class="img img-responsive col-md-4" src="images/blog-mini-01.jpg">

      <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="big-title" style="text-align:center">
<h3>This is a sample tfa jkljankjbfhbfklhabitle</h3>
</div>

<ul class="col-md-12">


         <li class="col-md-6 pull-left"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Fees</i></li>
         <li class="col-md-6 pull-right"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Rating</i></li>

       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Duration </i></li>
       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> University </i></li>

         </ul>
         </div>
       <div>
         <ul>
         <li class="col-md-6">
         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go to course>></a>
         </li>
         <li class="col-md-6">

         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Remove</a>
</li>         
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="drag41" class="gh col-md-12"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img class="img img-responsive col-md-4" src="images/blog-mini-01.jpg">

      <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="big-title" style="text-align:center">
<h3>This is a sample tfa jkljankjbfhbfklhabitle</h3>
</div>

<ul class="col-md-12">


         <li class="col-md-6 pull-left"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Fees</i></li>
         <li class="col-md-6 pull-right"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Rating</i></li>

       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Duration </i></li>
       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> University </i></li>

         </ul>
         </div>
       <div>
         <ul>
         <li class="col-md-6">
         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go to course>></a>
         </li>
         <li class="col-md-6">

         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Remove</a>
</li>         
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
      </li><li>
        <div id="drag465" class="gh col-md-12"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img class="img img-responsive col-md-4" src="images/blog-mini-01.jpg">

      <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="big-title" style="text-align:center">
<h3>This is a sample tfa jkljankjbfhbfklhabitle</h3>
</div>

<ul class="col-md-12">


         <li class="col-md-6 pull-left"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Fees</i></li>
         <li class="col-md-6 pull-right"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Rating</i></li>

       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Duration </i></li>
       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> University </i></li>

         </ul>
         </div>
       <div>
         <ul>
         <li class="col-md-6">
         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go to course>></a>
         </li>
         <li class="col-md-6">

         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Remove</a>
</li>         
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
      </li><li>
        <div id="drag45" class="gh col-md-12"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img class="img img-responsive col-md-4" src="images/blog-mini-01.jpg">

      <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="big-title" style="text-align:center">
<h3>This is a sample tfa jkljankjbfhbfklhabitle</h3>
</div>

<ul class="col-md-12">


         <li class="col-md-6 pull-left"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Fees</i></li>
         <li class="col-md-6 pull-right"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Rating</i></li>

       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Duration </i></li>
       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> University </i></li>

         </ul>
         </div>
       <div>
         <ul>
         <li class="col-md-6">
         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go to course>></a>
         </li>
         <li class="col-md-6">

         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Remove</a>
</li>         
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
      </li><li>
        <div id="drag47" class="gh col-md-12"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img class="img img-responsive col-md-4" src="images/blog-mini-01.jpg">

      <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="big-title" style="text-align:center">
<h3>This is a sample tfa jkljankjbfhbfklhabitle</h3>
</div>

<ul class="col-md-12">


         <li class="col-md-6 pull-left"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Fees</i></li>
         <li class="col-md-6 pull-right"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Rating</i></li>

       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Duration </i></li>
       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> University </i></li>

         </ul>
         </div>
       <div>
         <ul>
         <li class="col-md-6">
         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go to course>></a>
         </li>
         <li class="col-md-6">

         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Remove</a>
</li>         
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
      </li><li>
        <div id="drag48" class="gh col-md-12"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <img class="img img-responsive col-md-4" src="images/blog-mini-01.jpg">

      <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="big-title" style="text-align:center">
<h3>This is a sample tfa jkljankjbfhbfklhabitle</h3>
</div>

<ul class="col-md-12">


         <li class="col-md-6 pull-left"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Fees</i></li>
         <li class="col-md-6 pull-right"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Rating</i></li>

       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> Duration </i></li>
       <li class="col-md-6 pul"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"> University </i></li>

         </ul>
         </div>
       <div>
         <ul>
         <li class="col-md-6">
         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go to course>></a>
         </li>
         <li class="col-md-6">

         <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Remove</a>
</li>         
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 red">
<div class="col-md-6">
 <h4 style="text-align:center">Done</h4>

<section class="leftbox" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" >
 <button id="menu" onclick="changec()" class="pull-right fixed-top">+</button>
   </section>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<h4 style="text-align:center">Tracking</h4>
<section class="rightbox" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
 <button id="menu" onclick="changec2()" class="pull-right fixed-top">+</button>
 </section>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h4 style="text-align:center">Pursuing</h4>

<section class="leftbox2" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

   <button id="menu" onclick="changec3()" class="pull-right fixed-top">+</button>
</section>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h4 style="text-align:center">Dropped</h4>

<section class="rightbox2" id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

   <button id="menu" onclick="changec4()" class="pull-right fixed-top">+</button>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got help from this answer - [HTML disable Drop event, div box child contents overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847003/html-disable-drop-event-div-box-child-contents-overlap)
Modified your function a little. Try this.

```
     function drop(ev) {

        var eleid = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        var el = ev.target; 

        if (el.id != 'div1' && el.id != 'div2' && el.id != 'div3' && el.id != 'div4') {
           // el = el.parentNode;

            if(el.id != 'div6') {
                el = document.getElementById('div6');
            }               
        }
        el.appendChild(document.getElementById(eleid));
        ev.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot it worked.But when i increase the content of the div its not working.

Comment: In your css, you have class .gh having height: 50px; Did you try to increase that? That might be the issue.

Comment: I have made height to auto and inserted some images and buttons in nested divs.Now my divs look something like this :https://jsfiddle.net/994y3f92/

Comment: Does not work in fiddle. Can't drag anything only. But works at my place. Whatever you move up or down, will get appended at the bottom.  So number your samples to get better idea like sample 1, 2, etc...

Comment: I have edited the code,hope this might help you understand. :)

Comment: Edited the answer... Is this better?

Comment: Yes, but in wishlist if u drop one div on another it goes to the bottom automatically but in right boxes that is not happening. If i drop them on one another they are going back to wishlist, I need them to drop in the same box.Can something be done about that?

Comment: Can i have translucent text in the div and when i  drop something from wishlist it should disappear?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed target to currentTarget, and my elements no longer overlap each other when doing a drag and drop

```
function drop(even) {
        
        even.preventDefault();
        var fetchData = even.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        even.currentTarget.appendChild(document.getElementById(fetchData));
        

    }
```